# React-select: How to add created items to options list

Tags: reactjs, react-select

So I'm using the Creatable component of the `react-select` library. I want to be able to add the created option into my options array on keyDown.  [How it looks right now](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b9htkt?file=src%2FApp.js)

My states:

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [selectedValues, setselectedValues] = useState([]);

  const [current, setCurrent] = useState([]);

  const [selection, setSelection] = useState(statusOptions);
```

My functions

```
 const handleInputChange = (value) => {
    setInputValue(value);
  };
  const handleOnChange = (haha) => {
    setCurrent(haha);
  };

  const handleKeyDown = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setNewValues();
    }, [2700]);
  };

  const setNewValues = (event) => {
    const newOption = { label: inputValue, inputValue };
    inputValue !== '' && setSelection([...selection, newOption]);

    setCurrent(current);
    let difference = current.filter((x) => !value.includes(x));

    setInputValue('');

    setselectedValues(difference);
  };
```

How the component looks

```
<CreatableSelect
        options={selection}
        isMulti
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        value={selectedValues.selected}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      />
```

The problem: Right now, the inputValue is added to the dropdown list as the user types and i don't know why. I am able to add and delete the tags on keyDown. But when the user types slow or doesn't write quick enough, the dropdown list ends up with two created options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is getting added to the list because `setNewValues` is being called after the 2700 ms timer expires which is adding a new option item to the menu.

In order to achieve the behavior that you want, remove the `onKeyDown` function. This will allow you to enter tags without having them populate the menu.

##### Adding custom tag

[image: Adding custom tag]

##### Result of creating tag

[image: Result of creating tag]

Comment: Thanks! For some reason i thought i needed the keyDown event. Removed it and was able to make it work :)

Comment: Glad to have helped! Would you please mark this answer as correct if it allowed you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

So I was way over-complicating this. And thanks to the answer above, i was able to approach it better. I needed to be able to add the tags via keyboard, have them be added into the dropdown list, and then be able to get deleted. [Here's the full answer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b9htkt?file=src%2FApp.js)

```
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [selectedValues, setselectedValues] = useState({ selected: [] });

  const [selection, setSelection] = useState(statusOptions);

  const handleInputChange = (value) => {
    setInputValue(value);
  };

  const handleOnChange = () => {
    const newOption = { label: inputValue, inputValue };

    inputValue !== '' && setSelection([...selection, newOption]);

    setInputValue('');

    setselectedValues(selection);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <CreatableSelect
        options={selection}
        isMulti
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        value={selectedValues.selected}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        controlShouldRenderValue={true}
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: Glad to have helped!